# Jquery Top Package Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple packages for selection.

```
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack1" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack1" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack3" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-search="select">
<input name="pack3" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Same this, I have lots of items which belongs to different packages.

Here is my jQuery

```
  jQuery(".image-grid-item").click(function(){
     jQuery('input', this).prop("checked", true);
     //alert("test");

     if(jQuery('input[name="pack1"]').prop("checked") == true){        
        jQuery('.package1').show();
      }
      else if(jQuery('input[name="pack2"]').prop("checked") == true){        
        jQuery('.package2').show();
      }
      else if(jQuery('input[name="pack3"]').prop("checked") == true){        
        jQuery('.package3').show();
      }

      else{
        // jQuery('input',this).prop('checked', true);

      }
  });
```

Here is my div which show right package.

```
<div class="package1" style="display: none;">
package1
</div>
<div class="package2" style="display: none;">
package2
</div>
<div class="package3" style="display: none;">
package3
</div>
```

If I select package1 its showing right package, but when I select package1 and package3 its showing both packages, but I want to show just package3 only.
Or when I select package1 and package2 it need to show only bigger package means package2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple piece of logic that needs to be done. Please learn from this example and try to think through a problem or attempt to solve the issue before posting on here... it goes a long way.

See the code comments for an explanation of how this works.

```js
//When we click on the div

$('.image-grid-item').on('click', function() {
  var selected = [];

  //Allow a package to be selected & deslected
  if ($(this).children().prop('checked') == true) {
    $(this).children().prop('checked', false)
  } else {
    $(this).children().prop('checked', true)
  }


  //For every div on the pack
  $('.image-grid-item').each(function(index, element) {

    //Check if the input inside of it is checked
    if ($(element).children().prop('checked') == true) {

      // if it is checked then store the package number in the array
      selected.push($(element).data('package'));
    }
  });


  var packageSizes = [];
  //Loop through the array of selected packages we made earlier 
  $.each(selected, function(index, value) {

    //Then loop through each package div on the page
    $('.package').each(function(index, element) {
    
      /*If the current item in the loop has the same data attribute value
      as the div we are also currently looping, then... 
      */
      if ($(element).data('package') == value) {
      
        //Store the package size in the package array
        packageSizes.push($(element).data('size'))
      }
      
      //(Or in other words, if we check a box, store the package size in an array)
    });
  })


  //Now we have the sizes of w/e packages are selected, get the largest size
  var largestPackage = Math.max.apply(Math, packageSizes);

  //Hide all packages initiallly
  $('.package').hide();
  
  //Loop through all package divs
  $('.package').each(function(index, element) {
  
    //If the package's size is equal to the largest package we selected then...
    if ($(element).data('size') == largestPackage) {
    
      //Display only that largest package
      $(element).show();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.image-grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-grid-item" data-package="1" data-search="select">
  <label>size 5</label>
  <input name="pack1" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-package="2" data-search="select">
  <label>size 10</label>
  <input name="pack2" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="image-grid-item" data-package="3" data-search="select">
  <label>size 15</label>
  <input name="pack3" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="package" data-package="1" data-size="5" style="display: none;">
  package1
</div>
<div class="package" data-package="2" data-size="10" style="display: none;">
  package2
</div>
<div class="package" data-package="3" data-size="15" style="display: none;">
  package3
</div>
```

If you feel like this answer has resolved your issue then please hit the checkmark button next to the voting arrows. Comment below if you have further questions/queries regarding this answer.

It's also worth noting that this method can be reduced and made more efficient but I find writing like this makes it easier to follow and more readable.

Happy coding!

Comment: this is not, what I'm looking for. If I click on package1 and package2, it should be show package2. Multiple selection must be enable.

Comment: I have changed my answer, please try it again. Also, this isn't too different to what I originally wrote... it shouldn't have been to difficult to work it out from what I originally had but I digress.

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747017/select-large-data-size-attribute-from-autocomplete-search

Comment: your answer is good, its very help for me to achieve the target.  But now my scenario is changed. thats why I asked for answer. If you help me to fix this I will glad to you.

Comment: That's not how stack overflow works. You asked a specific question **here** and my solution works the question posted **here** - so you should accept **this** answer for **this** question. Your other question is **completely** separate. Don't try to hold my solutions hostage for other unrelated questions...